# Have a string but would like to format it into a date

Tags: python, zendesk

so I have a script that is pulling data out of our Zendesk(support CRM) installation and it's grabbing a couple of date fields via their REST API. The date fields come out like this: 2018-04-21T21:41:09Z and when I try to format it via Python, I get an error that the field itself is a string and won't accept `strptime` or `strhtime.` The exact error is:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strptime'

Any idea what I can do to convert this to something that I can reformat with `strptime` or the like? Python novice who is self-taught, so I'm probably missing something very obvious or basic.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime):

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('2018-04-21T21:41:09Z', "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
```